Extensibility of the solution of ODEs
I met the following problem:

Given $y^{\prime}=-y^3+p(x)$, where $p(x)$ is bounded and continuous. Prove that the solution of any initial problem $(x_0, y_0)$ can be extended to $\left[x_0,+\infty\right)$.

And I met an another problem, which looks similar:

Given $y^{\prime}=-y^3+a x^2+b x+c$, where $a,b,c\in \mathbb R$. Prove that the solution of any initial problem $(x_0, y_0)$ can be extended to $\left[x_0,+\infty\right)$.

I cannot work out any of these problems. The only theorem I know which can be used to prove extensibility is the following:

Theorem 2.17. Suppose $U=\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n$ and for every $T>0$ there are constants $M(T), L(T)$ such that
$$
|f(t, x)| \leq M(T)+L(T)|x|, \quad(t, x) \in[-T, T] \times \mathbb{R}^n .
$$
Then all solutions of the IVP $\dot{x}=f(t, x),  x\left(t_0\right)=x_0 $ are defined for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

(This theorem is from the book by Gerald Teschl) I have totally no idea how to apply this theorem to these problems.
Any advice will be appreciated.

The Theorem cannot be applied since $y \mapsto -y^3$ is growing superlinear. However, I think the following could work for both problems.
Let $p:[x_0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous (not necessarily bounded) and let $y:[x_0,\omega_+) \to \mathbb{R}$ be the right-nonextendable solution of the IVP $y'=-y^3+p(x)$, $y(x_0)=y_0$. Then $\omega_+= \infty$:
Assume that $\omega_+ < \infty$. Then, set
$$
b:= \max\{|y_0|^3, \max\{|p(x)|: x \in [x_0,\omega_+]\}\} +1, \quad c:=b^{1/3}.
$$
Note that $|y_0| < c$. We show that $|y(x)| < c$ $(x \in [x_0,\omega_+))$. Otherwise there is a first point $x_1 \in (x_0,\omega_+)$ such that $|y(x_1)| = c$, that is
$y(x_1)=c$ or $y(x_1)=-c$, and $|y(x)|< c$ $(x \in [x_0,x_1))$. Consider the case $y(x_1)=c$ (the case $y(x_1)=-c$ can be treated similar). Then
$y'(x_1)\ge 0$ but
$$
y'(x_1)= -c^3 + p(x_1) = -b + p(x_1) < 0,
$$
a contradiction.
Now, since $y$ is bounded, also $y'$ is bounded on $[x_0,\omega_+)$. Hence $y_1:=\lim_{x \to \omega_+} y(x)$ exists and we can extend $y$ to the right by a solution of the IVP $z'=-z^3 + p(x)$, $z(\omega_+)=y_1$, a contradiction.
